# Closing the main window in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c

How can i close a main window programatically in cocoa?

I want to close my main window in a timer function(`NSTimer`) when a boolean value is set?
How can I do that, I don't want to terminate my application, But would like to just close my window.

Comment: Closing the main window should not terminate the application by default.

Answer (score 2):

Something as simple as:

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay target:[NSApp mainWindow] selector:@selector(performClose:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`

should work (where `delay` is an `NSTimeInterval` with your desired wait time).

Comment: Actually I want NSApplicationMain() to return when the UI closes.

Comment: Returning from NSApplicationMain() kind of implies application termination. :)